# Is it easy to get a visa for France if one already has a visa for the UK and applies from the UK?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, france, russian-citizens

For a Russian citizen:

If I have a general purpose (6 months) visa for the UK, and am currently in the UK, does that make it easier to get a visa for France.

For example: I'm in the UK on the general purpose visa for a 3 month holiday, and I would like to visit Paris. So if I wander into the French embassy in London are they likely to give a French visa easily on the basis that I already jumped through all the hoops for the UK visa?

Comment: Incidentally, don't wander into the French embassy ;-) Visas are processed by the consulate (another building, 700m away), application have apparently been outsourced to some external company and are accepted on appointment only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, **no**.  Remember, you're dealing with a bunch of government bureaucrats here, you'll still need to satisfy [every item on their checklist](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/IMG/pdf/visagb.pdf).

That said, having evidence of previous travel and (the important part!) having returned home will be helpful in proving that you're not planning to migrate to the EU permanently.  However, I don't think you'll be able to apply while still in the UK, since [the French only let UK residents apply for visas in the UK](http://www.ambafrance-uk.org/How-and-where-to-apply-for-a-visa).

The good news is that obtaining a Schengen visa is relatively easy compared to getting a UK visa: lower application fees, shorter application forms, less supporting documentation needed, more locations where one may apply (VFS global offices in 15+ cities, if you apply from Russia), a straightforward application process, shorter processing times.