# Schengen visa from UK for Indian citizen

Tags: schengen, uk, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen holding a regular passport, can I apply for a Schengen visa from within the UK?

Comment: It might depend on your situation in the UK (whether you are resident or not, or some similar distinction). Being an Indian citizen is not relevant, beyond the fact that you require a visa in the first place. See, e.g., http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18478/is-it-easy-to-get-a-visa-for-france-if-one-already-has-a-visa-for-the-uk-and-app

Comment: In short: Yes, you can, it's not forbidden to apply for a Schengen visa in the UK (and since British citizens don't need one, only people with other citizenships – including India – apply there). Whether it's possible for you at the moment depends on details you haven't provided (where do you want to apply and what's your status in the UK). You might also want to do some basic research on your own (e.g. check the relevant consulate's website) to create a more interesting question for this site.

Answer (score 2):

According to the website of the [Embassy of Belgium in the UK](http://countries.diplomatie.belgium.be/en/united_kingdom/travel_belgium/visa_belgium/)

> You should apply for your visa in person at the Belgian embassy or consulate which is competent for  your country of residence

The rules should be similar or identical for other Schengen countries.

Thus, if you can apply in the UK only if you are a resident of the UK.